# defining storage database in genexus ev3

Tags: android, database, storage, genexus

I was using genexus tilo to develop Android applications.
I always defined that the database would be stored in SDCard in file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Artech\GeneXus\GeneXusXEv3\Android\Templates\src\com\genexus\namespace\MainApplication.java`.

However, yesterday I has instaled GeneXus Ev3 and now the database is being stored in the internal of device, even if I defined `application.setUseInternalStorageForDatabase(false)` in the file.

This way, I can´t copy or replace the database file.

Has anything changed in GeneXus ev3?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There where not changes in that settings in Gx Ev3.

Please verify that you have change the correct file for this version of Genexus.

Then uninstall the app and run it again with an F5.

You can verify that your setting get applied in the target file:

**(your KB)\mobile\android\main(namespace)\MainApplication.java**

**Note**:

In some cases the files form SD card are not getting refresh in File explorer immediately, please try disconnect and reconnect the device.

Also, you can try using app like "**AirDroid**", very useful to copy files from computer to device and from device to computer.

In SDK platform-tools you can try "**adb pull**", in your case, something like:

```
adb pull  /sdcard/Android/data/com.artech.revenewmobileandroid.revenewmobile/f‌​iles/db/revenewmobile.sqlite c:\revenewmobile.sqlite
```

could work.

Comment: I verified the file you mentioned and it is right, it is equal the other at the installation folder.

application.setIsOfflineApplication(true);
application.setUseInternalStorageForDatabase(false);

But it doesn´t work.

Comment: can you send your apk (just an example) to test/reproduce the problem?

Comment: We are running with this same problem. 

Device: Samsung Galaxy S4 |

OS Version: 4.4.2 |

GX Version: GeneXus Evolution 3 Release |

The log is telling us that the database is being created in the emulated folder:

08-14 12:04:28.390: D/GeneXusApplication(32206): Create database in: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.artech.revenewmobileandroid.revenewmobile/files/db/revenewmobile.sqlite

And our folder where it should be on our sdcard is empty.
/storage/extSDCard/Android/Data/<myApp>/files

Were you guys able to fix this problem?